# Slash "/" is missed in string function argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def classify_images(images_dir = r"pet_images/", results_dic = None, model = 'resnet'):
    for key in results_dic:
        results_dic[key].append(classifier(images_dir + key, model).lower())
        if results_dic[key][0] in results_dic[key][1]:
            results_dic[key].append('1')
        else:
            results_dic[key].append('0')

classify_images(in_arg.dir, results, in_arg.arch)
```

This definition doesn't work as "/" sign in images_dir string is not passed along to classifier() function. When I put string directly in classifier function it works properly:

```
def classify_images(images_dir = r'pet_images/', results_dic = None, model = 'resnet'):
    for key in results_dic:
        results_dic[key].append(classifier('pet_images/' + key, model).lower())
        if results_dic[key][0] in results_dic[key][1]:
            results_dic[key].append('1')
        else:
            results_dic[key].append('0')

classify_images(in_arg.dir, results, in_arg.arch)
```

It results in:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pet_imagesBasenji_00963.jpg'
```

Any ideas why slash sign is somehow disappearing when put in function definition as default argument?

Comment: Are you perhaps calling `classify_images()` with `'pet_images'` as the first argument?

Comment: You're not *using* the default!

Comment: Aside: take a look at [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) or at least [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html). Building paths by sticking strings together is fragile.

Comment: It's just a part of AI course project. I need to call classify_images() as in the question - edited a moment ago.

Comment: Your sample code does not show the contents of the `in_arg.dir` variable being passed as an argument to the `classify_images()` function (which overrides the default value for the argument you have in the function definition).

Comment: @JakubBielan, the argument you pass in when you call the function takes precedent over the argument's default value.

Comment: Use `os.path.join` to string together paths

Comment: What @Tgsmith61591 said is good advice, but that's not the problem here.

Comment: I also put the exact error. It looks like it took the string but without a slash. To be honest I'm not sure what in_arg.dir and in_arg.arch exactly mean. That's why I just put default values for agruments. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 - thank you! It works.

Comment: Agree with @martineau. Although it is highly encouraged to always use `os.path.join` to safely connect paths, the `string` + `string` here should be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the contents of `in_arg.dir` with `print(in_arg.dir)` and see if it is the same as what you expect it to be, in this case, you are expecting `pet_images/`.

Alternatively, you can use your defined keyword argument with:

```
def classify_images(images_dir = r"pet_images/", results_dic = None, model = 'resnet'):
    for key in results_dic:
        results_dic[key].append(classifier(images_dir + key, model).lower())
        if results_dic[key][0] in results_dic[key][1]:
            results_dic[key].append('1')
        else:
            results_dic[key].append('0')

classify_images(images_dir = r"pet_images/", results_dic = results, mode = in_arg.arch)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tgsmith61591 solution works perfectly.

```
import os

def classify_images(images_dir = r"pet_images/", results_dic = None, model = 'resnet'):
    for key in results_dic:
        results_dic[key].append(classifier(os.path.join(images_dir, key), model).lower())
        if results_dic[key][0] in results_dic[key][1]:
            results_dic[key].append('1')
        else:
            results_dic[key].append('0')

classify_images(in_arg.dir, results, in_arg.arch)
```

Comment: Great stuff! But generally not knowing what you are passing through your function is also dangerous, just to note.

Comment: Thanks for help @BernardL. I'm not sure why they used 'in_arg.dir' and 'in_arg.arch'. I'd personally put arguments when calling the function. I'm a newbie though ;)

Comment: You can refer to the answer I posted to easily see what values they actually store and whether you are using the right arguments. In any case, happy learning!

Comment: Using `os.path.join(images_dir, key)` supplies the needed separator if it's not already present in the arguments passed to it (so it's hard to say if there's one at end of the `in_arg.dir` argument being used in the call to  `classify_images()` or not)—so I guess using it would be the safest approach (as well as the recommended way to join path components since it's OS-independent).